# Cannot make app go to main menu (Swift 4 SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift4

I am trying to direct the user to a main menu file as soon my game loads (made with Swift 4 SpriteKit). However, when I try to redirect the user to this .swift file (where a label should be displayed onto the users screen) the screen is simply blank except the for the node and FPS counter.

Here's my code in the MainMenuScene.swift file I created:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class MainMenu: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        print("In scene")
        let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
        myLabel.fontColor = SKColor.blue
        myLabel.text = "My Label"
        myLabel.fontSize = 50
        myLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        myLabel.zPosition = 1
        self.addChild(myLabel)
    }


}
```

Here's my code in the GameViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "MainMenuScene") {
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
            view.showsPhysics = true
        }
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .allButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

I changed the

```
if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
```

to

```
if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "MainMenuScene")
```

That line of code should redirect the user to MainMenuScene.swift, but when I run the program the screen is simply blank.
Anyone know what im doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Take a good look at your scene file with the Interface Builder.

Comment: @ElTomato my MainMenuScene file?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it...

Comment: you have the class name as MainMenu and are calling fileNamed as "MainMenuScene" is this correct? try `MainMenu(fileNamed: "MainMenuScene")`

Comment: @RonMyschuk changed it, but it still doesn't work? Just a blank screen?

Comment: is your mainMenu scene created in the Scene editor or is it solely laid out in code?

Comment: Soley laid out in code

Answer (score -1):

Try using the code below after

```
    super.viewDidLoad()
```

Also make sure that your Menu class is called "MainMenuScene" and that you changed the scene name to the same at MainMenuScene.sks[image]

CODE:

```
 if let scene = GKScene(fileNamed: "MainMenuScene") {

        // Get the SKScene from the loaded GKScene
        if let sceneNode = scene.rootNode as! MainMenuScene? {

           scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            if let view = self.view as! SKView? {


                view.presentScene(sceneNode)

                view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

                //view.showsFPS = true
                //view.showsNodeCount = true
            }
        }
    }
```